# Making a Kendo datasource filterable (searchable)

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to make my Kendo datasource filterable. This is my code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, letter: "A" },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33, letter: "B" }
  ],
    template: "${name} ${age}",
    group: "letter",

    filterable: { placeholder: "Type to search...", field: "age" },
    fixedHeaders: true

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-template="contactsTemplate" data-source="dataSource"></ul>
```

The search bar does not show. I need to get the search bar showing somehow. Thanks.

Attempting to do the technique in the answer below:

```
function setUp() {
    $("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "age",
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Search"
});
}

<input id="countries" data-source="dataSource" /><br /><br /><br />
  <ul id="flat-listview" data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-template="contactsTemplate" data-source="dataSource"></ul>
```

Comment: You say _I need to get the search bar showing somehow_ but the question is where do you want it to show? You show a template but doesn't say anything what do you use it for. It seems that there is some missing details on your questions...

Comment: @OnaBai I need the search bar to show absolutely anywhere. The top would be fantastic. Yes my template seems to do nothing also. It is displaying only the name. I show my updated code in the question

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to filter a List view using a search functionality

You will need a Kendo AutoComplete as a search widget

I have created a jsfiddler for you see .

```
var Data = [{
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: "30"
}, {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: "33"
}];

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: Data,
    pageSize: 15
});


//create AutoComplete UI component
$("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "age",
    dataSource: dataSource,
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Search"
});


$("#listView").kendoListView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chanaka1/512gjavv/2/

Mobile Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/chanaka1/x09tk3xm/1/

Comment: Thank you. It is meant to work how I am using it, by specifying a "filterable" attribute, it is meant to add in a search box. See this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-listview/filtering. However I am looking in to your way because the other way is not working.

Comment: I did not know it is Kendo mobile you need , anyway what you have done is wrong you need to filter the mobile list view not the data-source . here I have created a mobile list view Demo 

http://jsfiddle.net/chanaka1/x09tk3xm/1/

and if the Answer is correct please accept the answer

Comment: Thank you, I will try that tomorrow when I get to work. However, I have actually previously managed to do it that way. Instantiating the listview in js code always seemed to lead to more problems though such as multiple search bars as it got instantiated more than once, which is why i started to state it is a listview with the HTML data-role attribute instead of ever instantiating it in js code. Is it possible to add that search bar, when the listview is instantiated with the HTML data-role attribute rather than js code?

Comment: don't think filterable is possible through data attribute

Comment: I was trying to add it to the listview programmatically in js code